# How difficult is it to convert Tableau dashboards to Power BI?

Tags: visualization, tableau-api, powerbi

I have few projects lined up wherein visuals in Tableau needs to be converted to power BI, Is there any tools available to do so.

please share your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no tool that converts Tableau worksheet to PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert Tableau dashboards to PowerBi. However, you can try to replicate a visualization in Tableau in PowerBi. The degree of similarity will highly depend on the tools and features used in the Tableau dasboard which are proprietary to Tableau. If , say, a Tableau chart used is not present in PowerBi, then you are out of luck, unless you are good at programming! Then you can create a custom visual in PowerBi to be used in your dashboard.

And look at [Powerbi Improvements suggestion](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/12518829-export-a-dashboard-i-have-built-in-tableau-to-powe) ,They have this suggestion,Hoping to see it soon in the future.